# Docker volume to authorize composer and symfony to write in the project folder

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, composer-php

How authorizing the docker php container to write in the project folder?

```
  php:
    build:
      context: .docker/php
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/server:cached
      - ./:/var/www/symfony
      - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
      - ./.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    user: "${ID_USER:-1001}:${ID_USER:-1001}"
```

After a `docker-composer exec php composer install`, I have this error message:

```
In Git.php line 471:
                                                                                                                                                                             
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://github.com/hide/hideResourceBundle.git' '/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-hide-hideResourceBundle  
  .git/'                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                             
  fatal: could not create leading directories of '/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-hide-hideResourceBundle.git'
```

Comment: Please share more details. What are the current permissions? And how is this problem related to Symfony?

Comment: @NicoHaase the issue is clear enough and if you  think it is not related to Symfony then feel free to ask to remove that tag. It is obvious that the user did not know what it is exactly related to so he reached for a broader help. the current permissions are right there, defined in the docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to install then you should do it as root:

```
docker-compose exec -u "0:0" php composer install
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase please tell me which part is not clear to you and I will elaborate. I explained the reason (cannot install if not root) and the solution (how to run the command as root)